Migrated from Magento 1.9.2 to 2.4.6-p5, after migration all category urls showing 404
Migrated from Magento 1.9.2 to 2.4.6-p5, after migration all category urls showing 404.
Any Idea how to solve this issue?
I have tried options like re-indexing, cache clear, setup:upgrade, di-compile,  but no luck
Search page also showing no products,
I have installed Elastic search 7 on server.

It works for me for this extension https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites
run the command: php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate --entity-type=category

You need to regenerate category url. Used this extension with success: https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites.
